# What command runs when I SSH into a server?

Tags: server, bash, ssh, command-line

When I SSH into a server, I see the MOTD then I am in BASH. What command is running that takes care of displaying the MOTD and then starts the shell?

Answer (score 1):

That's generally `/bin/login`, but `ssh` is usually a special case — unless `UseLogin yes` is specified in the `sshd_config`, it does the session setup itself.  Much of the session is actually managed via PAM, though.

`/etc/motd` is often printed by `/etc/profile` or a script sourced from there; it's read by your login shell.

Comment: Say you are using a different shell, does `ssh` figure out which shell to run?

Comment: The shell comes from `/etc/passwd` or LDAP (or other directory service such as NIS), along with information like your home directory, numeroc user ID, and group memberships. You may be able to determine where by inspecting `/etc/nsswitch.conf`, and see your entry with `getent passwd $USER`.